# Prevent display Mapbox GL JS popup on double click event

Tags: popup, mapbox-gl-js, double-click

I found an unexpected behavior related with the Mapbox GL JS popup feature identifications.

I'm using the following event:

```
map.on('click', this._showPopup(e));
```

but when I make a double click and the zoom in is made, the popup is shown and close several times.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix you can do is to disable doubleClickZoom mapbox options.

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#doubleclickzoom